# MacBook Pro 2017 - Anti Evil Maid ideas

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, security

I have 2017 Mac Book Pro which does not have T1 or T2 chip. I am looking to detect and prevent [Evil Maid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_maid_attack) type attacks. I did some search and found [Do Not Disturb](https://objective-see.org/products/dnd.html). I don't find it sufficient. I am looking for some solution that verifies firmware / boot integrity similar to what T1 or T2 chip provides. Below are my questions

1. Are there any security features out of the box in 2017 MacBook Pro that ensures boot and firmware integrity. Articles related to the subject usually talks about T1 or T2 chips and does not mention anything other than that.
2. What solutions are available to detect and prevent any attempts of tampering that involves physical access?
3. Is there any solution similar to *Nitro Key* or [Librem Key](https://puri.sm/products/librem-key/) that ensures boot integrity available for 2017 MacBook Pro?

Comment: This is currently rather broad, it may also help to show the results of any research you already did on the topic.

Comment: Having said that: which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: "which version of macOS are you running" -- I am running Ventura

Comment: Ah, there is a builtin functionality called Do Not Disturb as well, thanks for the link to clarify this.

Comment: Ventura comes with SSV. While this probably doesn't protect against all possible "evil maid" type of attacks, it ensures that the OS hasn't been modified behind your back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any security features out of the box in 2017 MacBook Pro that ensures boot and firmware integrity.

#### Yes.  Apple's EFI is  digitally signed

This is a feature native to UEFI and although optional, Apple has been using them since switching to an EFI framework back in 2006.  Additionally, firmware *must* be newer than the one being replaced (can't be downgraded).

From [UEFI firmware security in an Intel-based Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/uefi-firmware-security-in-an-intel-based-mac-seced055bcf6/web)

> For an Intel-based Mac without the Apple T2 Security Chip, the root of trust for the UEFI firmware is the chip where the firmware is stored. UEFI firmware updates are digitally signed by Apple and verified by the firmware before updating the storage. To help prevent rollback attacks, updates must always have a version newer than the existing one.

It's important to note that this is *not foolproof*.  While there are security measures in place, someone with "hands on" access could still potentially modify the firmware in the pre-boot area of UFEI (this is why the T2 chip was invented).

> Likewise, if vulnerabilities are found in the early boot process of the UEFI firmware (before it write-restricts the storage chip), this could also lead to persistent infection of the UEFI firmware.

It's just to do this, it is "cost" prohibitive meaning not only would you need physical access, you'd have to have number of factors in your favor (a non-encrypted disk or be able to install a firmware image that didn't predate the existing one, and have it's digital signature spoofed for example) to get this malware on board.  It's not impossible, but it's impractical.

> What solutions are available to detect and prevent any attempts of tampering that involves physical access?

Realistically speaking, if you are a high value target (you'll know if you are one or work for one), you will have taken steps to mitigate this risk like upgrade your Mac to one with a T2 chip, implement security policies like smart card or 2FA hardware token based authentication and session lock after a very short period of inactivity.  You'll also have user use policies that put folks on the hook for compromising security (like losing your token and not reporting it).

The bottom line is if you are very concerned about firmware being compromised, upgrade to a newer Mac with the security built in (T2 chip).

#### About Librem Key and Nitro Key

> Is there any solution similar to Nitro Key or Librem Key that ensures boot integrity available for 2017 MacBook Pro?

Both of those products will not work here.  They cannot verify a UEFI firmware image.  They are for BIOS architecture only.

Will there be other (UEFI enabled) tools to protect you?  [Microsoft defender has UEFI scanning](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2020/06/17/uefi-scanner-brings-microsoft-defender-atp-protection-to-a-new-level/) and Anti-Virus companies like [Kasperky have added UEFI scanning](https://www.kaspersky.com/antivirus-for-uefi).  However, I haven't found any for macOS; the market might not be big enough to warrant the development time.

Comment: "if you are a high value target" -- One does not have to be high value target to be targeted. People do stuff like this for far less.

Comment: "upgrade to a newer Mac with the security built in (T2 chip)" -- Macs are very costly, upgrade is not a easy option for me.